# "Lost connection to 'My Mac'" on every debugger interaction

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, debugging

I'm trying to debug my program. The breakpoint works, but when I click Step Over (or do anything else with the debugger) Xcode says:

[image]

I've tried deleting the derived data and cleaning the project, and that doesn't help. I'm using OS X 10.11 and Xcode 7.2.

Edit: It seems to have something to do with my project. The code is at https://github.com/vindo-app/vindo, I'm working on the `menu` branch. The breakpoint is at Models/Start/StartMenu.m in `-addItemAtURL:`

[image]

Comment: How are you doing on memory? I've seen similar behavior when the app loads a lot of resources early in the app lifecycle. Try looking at it in Instruments.

Comment: I don't think there's any problem with that, my program hardly loads anything. The problem only happens once the breakpoint hits. Could it have anything to do with the fact that the breakpoint is in an FSEvents callback?

Comment: I don't see any Models dir. at that github project...?

Comment: The GitHub project doesn't have a `Models` directory, do you need to push it?  The last updates to the code in the repo are from a month ago.  If I open it up in Xcode, it doesn't show a `Models` folder either.  Other than that, if I add a breakpoint somewhere else in the code, I can continue properly.

Comment: @Gilderman There's a Models group in Xcode. I added a picture.

Comment: @Gliderman I forgot to say you need to check out the `menu` branch.

Comment: Tested the `menu` branch on OS X 10.11 and 10.11.1, both with Xcode 7.2.  Breakpoints seemed to work fine.  Installed a simple Windows program that had a Start Menu item, and it hit the breakpoint properly.  Continuing and step-over worked properly.  I'm not sure what the difference is, but everything seems fine here.  Have you restarted Xcode/computer yet?

Comment: @Gliderman The problem doesn't happen the first time the breakpoint fires. But when you continue the first time, and then install a program with a start menu item, it won't work when it hits the breakpoint the second time.

Comment: I am unable to get it to happen a "first time and then install a program".  It only fires the breakpoint during the installation of the program (presumably while adding to the menu).  Every time it has hit the breakpoint (there were exactly 4 calls that hit the breakpoint for the program I installed, and 2 icons added to the menu), I have been able to continue successfully.

Comment: @Gliderman It seems to have something to do with the fact that I'm using the "Debug and Reset" scheme, which removes some files and deletes some defaults domains before running. If you use that scheme, the breakpoint will fire once during initialization.

Comment: Finally got it to hit the breakpoint on startup with "Debug and Reset".  Clicked "continue", installed program, breakpoint was hit, I "stepped over" then "continued", breakpoint hit 3 more times (in total, 2 `.plist`, 2 `.icns`) and "continued" after each one.  I never lost connection with "My Mac".  For spec reference, this computer is a Core 2 Duo 2.26GHz with 4GB of RAM running 10.11.1.

Comment: @Gliderman Weird. Here's what's happening to me: https://youtu.be/rQGpobGGlOY. Not sure what is different about what you're doing. Sorry about the abhorrent video quality, my bandwidth is among the worst in the world.